# screen casting on the Mac

Tags: mac, screencasts

What's the best software for recording screencasts on the Mac? I've seen some good screencasts before that zoom in when the creator starts typing, allowing you to see what is actually being written. They also work with the microphone so you can record your voice. I'm looking for something with both of these features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snapz Pro](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) is allegedly the gold standard.

You may also be interested in the tips [here](http://soylentfoo.jnewland.com/articles/2007/01/31/how-to-make-a-screencast-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) to Snapz Pro. At $100, it is more expensive but I think it addresses your requirements elegantly...